# find between which two consecutive numbers of a quadratic sequence a given number belongs to

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find in which "bin" a particular number belongs to.
For example, consider the quadratic sequence -- $1, 4, 10, 22 \cdots$; so I want to find in which bin a query number belongs to. By bins, I mean $1-3, 4-9, 10-21 \cdots$. I know how to find the general term of a quadratic sequence. So I tried computing the difference between two consecutive terms and then tried mapping the query number ($q$) to a "bin number" using some formulas which I tried to guess -- as an example, the general term of the previously mentioned sequence is $\frac{3n^2 - 3n + 2}{2}$ and then difference between consecutive terms is $3n$, so I tried formulas like $\log_3q, \log_2(q + 3), \log_2(q - 3)$ (the base $2$ is because the "bin size" is doubling $3, 6, 12 \cdots$). But none of them seems to work in general. Can anyone give an expression for this, and a rigorous way of arriving at it?

EDIT:
I found the answer by hitting more guesses, the "bin number" for the particular example given in the question is given by: $$bin = \left\lfloor \log_2 \left\lfloor \frac{q - 1}{3 + 1} \right \rfloor \right \rfloor  + 1$$
But this is not a rigorous method and I don't know how to generalise this to other arbitrary quadratic sequences $T_n = an^2 + bn + c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quadratic formula to solve for the term number.  Given a value that is not a term number, you will get a fractional value for the term number.  In your example $$T_n=\frac 32n^2-\frac 32n+1\\n=\frac 13\left(\frac 32+\sqrt{\frac 94+6(T_n-1)}\right)$$
Given a value, plug it in for $T_n$, compute $n$ and round down to get the bin number.

Comment: That is so clean and simple. But does that mean: $$\left\lfloor \log_2 \left\lfloor \frac{q - 1}{3 + 1} \right \rfloor \right \rfloor  + 1 =\left\lfloor \frac 13\left(\frac 32+\sqrt{\frac 94+6(q-1)}\right) \right \rfloor$$?

Comment: No.  The left side grows logarithmically while the right grows as $\sqrt{\frac{2q}3}$.  I don't think you checked for large enough $q$